# Batch - How do I get it to display from all letters?

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple (I hope it doesn't become complicated) batch file in which you enter in a series of letters, (possibly seperated by spaces) and it 'decrypts them' similar to those old 'decoder wheels', in this case where A=1, B=2, and so forth

This is what I have so far, but I wish to make it so it can find what you put in all together, rather than having to enter in each letter one at a time. Thanks

`echo off
    cls`

```
:1
echo Enter in letters to decrypt
set /p let=
if %let%==A echo 1
if %let%==B echo 2
if %let%==C echo 3
if %let%==D echo 4
if %let%==E echo 5
if %let%==F echo 6
if %let%==G echo 7
if %let%==H echo 8
if %let%==I echo 9
if %let%==J echo 10
if %let%==K echo 11
if %let%==L echo 12
if %let%==M echo 13
if %let%==N echo 14
if %let%==O echo 15
if %let%==P echo 16
if %let%==Q echo 17
if %let%==R echo 18
if %let%==S echo 19
if %let%==T echo 20
if %let%==U echo 21
if %let%==V echo 22
if %let%==W echo 23
if %let%==X echo 24
if %let%==Y echo 25
if %let%==Z echo 26
```

Comment: FWIW the process of changing a letter or word to something else is `encryption`.  To change it back to readable text is decryption.  You might be interested in ROT13 if you haven't yet come across it - Rotate 13 encryption.  If you encrypt it twice then it becomes normal text again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CHOICE /C ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ /N
echo %errorlevel%
```